# Get the value only if a new value comes after subscribing

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I am uisng ngrx/store.

```
this.store
      .select(s => s.products && s.products.name)
      .filter(name => !!name)
      .subscribe(name => {
        // Now if there is a `name` in the store, it will run immediately
        // However, I want to get the `name`, only if a new value comes after subscribing
        console.log(name);
      });
```

I tried to add `.publish()` before `.subscribe`, but then I cannot get any value.

How can I get `name`, only if a new value comes after subscribing? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you subscribe, the current state of the store will be returned. If you don't want the current state, then you can skip the first response.
this.store.select(...).skip(1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the following for this:

- Hot vs. cold observables
- Back pressure (in your case a tolerance of 0)

Comment: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/backpressure.md 